# ld cannot find an existing library

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, shared-objects

I am attempting to link an application with g++ on this Debian lenny system. ld is complaining it cannot find specified libraries. The specific example here is ImageMagick, but I am having similar problems with a few other libraries too.

I am calling the linker with:

```
g++ -w (..lots of .o files/include directories/etc..) \
-L/usr/lib -lmagic
```

ld complains:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmagic
```

However, libmagic exists:

```
$ locate libmagic.so
/usr/lib/libmagic.so.1
/usr/lib/libmagic.so.1.0.0
$ ls -all /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    17 2008-12-01 03:52 /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1 -> libmagic.so.1.0.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 84664 2008-09-09 00:05 /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1.0.0
$ ldd /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1.0.0 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7f85000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7f51000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7df6000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7f86000)
$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep "libmagic"
    libmagic.so.1 -> libmagic.so.1.0.0
```

How do I diagnose this problem further, and what could be wrong? Am I doing something completely stupid?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The problem is the linker is looking for `libmagic.so` but you only have `libmagic.so.1`

A quick hack is to symlink `libmagic.so.1` to `libmagic.so`

Comment: that works, I am kind of perplexed that it would name the file in a completely useless way by default - can you provide any insight why it would do this by default?

Comment: Most likely it is a misconfiguration of the install script

Comment: The foo.so.1 is a symlink to foo.so.1.0.0 too.  This way, you can have several versions of a library in your system, and if an application needs a specific one, it can link to it, while in general, the newest one is chosen by symlink.  I do not know why this symlink was missing.

Comment: libmagic.so.1 is the soname, used by the dynamic linker; libmagic.so is used by the linker, and is usually together with the headers in the -dev package. The symlink might be missing because the -dev package was not installed.

Comment: I had the same problem... instead of doing the "hack" I installed the "*-devel" version and it fixed the compilation.

Comment: Same problem here and got crazy for a day... Actually it is better to let libraries hanle everything and, as Trevor stated, install devel packages...

Comment: How to symlink libmagic.so.1 to libmagic.so? And where to find those "devel" packages

Comment: @Black `ln -s path-to-libmagic.so.1/libmagic.so.1 path-to-libmagic.so.1/libmagic.so`. Example: `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so`

Answer (score 70):

As just formulated by grepsedawk, the answer lies in the `-l` option of `g++`, calling `ld`. If you look at the man page of this command, you can either do:

- `g++ -l:libmagic.so.1 [...]`
- or: `g++ -lmagic [...]` , if you have a symlink named libmagic.so in your libs path

Comment: Or in summary, remove the `lib` prefix when linking to it when using `-l`.  `-llibmagic` should be `-lmagic`.

Answer (score 35):

It is Debian convention to separate shared libraries into their runtime components (`libmagic1: /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1 → libmagic.so.1.0.0`) and their development components (`libmagic-dev: /usr/lib/libmagic.so → …`).

Because the library's soname is `libmagic.so.1`, that's the string that gets embedded into the executable so that's the file that is loaded when the executable is run.

However, because the library is specified as `-lmagic` to the linker, it looks for `libmagic.so`, which is why it is needed for development.

See [Diego E. Pettenò: Linkers and names](http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2010/10/08/linkers-and-names) for details on how this all works on Linux.

---

In short, you should `apt-get install libmagic-dev`.  This will not only give you `libmagic.so` but also other files necessary for compiling like `/usr/include/magic.h`.

Answer (score 10):

In Ubuntu, you can install `libtool` which resolves the libraries automatically.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtool
```

This resolved a problem with `ltdl` for me, which had been installed as `libltdl.so.7` and wasn't found as simply `-lltdl` in the make.

Comment: it did not solve the error  **cannot fine -LGL** . could you please give more information on what libtool does and how it solves library issues?

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned above the linker is looking for `libmagic.so`, but you only have `libmagic.so.1`.

To solve this problem just perform an update cache.

```
ldconfig -v
```

To verify you can run:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libmagic
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm badly mistaken `libmagic` or `-lmagic` is not the same library as ImageMagick. You state that you want ImageMagick.

ImageMagick comes with a utility to supply all appropriate options to the compiler.

Ex:

```
g++ program.cpp `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs` -o "prog"
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing libgl1-mesa-dev from the Ubuntu repo resolved this problem for me.

Comment: Surely you're not suffering from the same script bug as maxpenguin in 2008.

Comment: it solved my problem . could you please give more information on what it is . and how it solves this issue ? (i mean : libgl1-mesa-dev) . thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried all solutions mentioned above but none of them solved my issue but finally I solved it with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

This will do the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to install the `-devel` package.

If the compiler is looking for `libabc.so` while you have `libabc.so.1`, you need to install the `-devel` package like `libabc-devel` as `libabc.so.1` is a runtime lib but `libabc.so` is a development lib.