# How to link a specific version of a shared library in makefile without using LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: c, gcc, openssl, shared-libraries

I know that [LD_LIBRARY_PATH is evil](http://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/avoiding_ld_library_path_the) and it's a good habit to avoid using it.
I have a program called `server.c` on a remote Solaris 9 server that holds two versions of openssl library (0.9.8 and 1.0.0) and I'm using gcc 3.4.6. My program need to link to 1.0.0a version. Because it's work environment, I don't have the right to modify anything in the openssl library directory. I figured out to compile my program with both `-L` and `-R` options without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and it worked fine. (I noticed it won't work without setting `-R` option) But the compiled program kept linking to `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8` instead of `/.../libssl.so.1.0.0`. Is there a work-around for this?

BTW, please correct me if I'm wrong: is it the `-R` option that actually "link" the shared libraries at runtime and `-L` option only "load" shared libraries at compile time?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Z.Zen

//////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is my **Makefile**:

```
CC = gcc
OPENSSLDIR = /usr/local/ssl
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -W -I${OPENSSLDIR}/include -O2 -D_REENTRANT -D__EXTENSIONS__ 

RPATH = -R${OPENSSLDIR}/lib
LD = ${RPATH} -L${OPENSSLDIR}/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lsocket -lnsl -lpthread

OBJS = common.o

PROGS = server

all: ${PROGS}

server: server.o ${OBJS}
        ${CC} server.o ${OBJS} -o server ${LD}


clean:;
        ${RM} ${PROGS} *.ln *.BAK *.bak *.o
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out that I can include the absolute path of the specific library that I want to link to and it worked fine for me:

```
LD = ${RPATH} -lsocket -lnsl -lpthread ${OPENSSLDIR}/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 \
         ${OPENSSLDIR}/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

If you are using **g++**, [Piotr Lesnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38796/piotr-lesnicki) pointed out that `-l:libssl.so.1.0.0` also works. See more at the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/linux-gcc-linking-ld-cannot-find-a-library-that-exists).

Comment: I find that for gcc -l: does not work, but it will not produce an error either and still tries to link to something.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any links to the SSL lib?
If not, can you create a link to the the desired SSL lib like

```
ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so
```

in the ssl directory and try it

Comment: yeah, symlink is a good way to do it but sometimes I need to link to older version of the openssl library. I want something that I can change every time I compile my program. But thanks, it works!