# how can I guide compiler to use a certain library?

Tags: linux, compilation, linker

I'm trying to compile skeltrack according to this guide http://tayyabnaseer.blogspot.com.tr/2012/05/installing-skeltrack-on-ubuntu.html

I successfully compiled and installed first two libraries. However when it comes to skeltrack I get followin compilation error:

```
CCLD     test-skeleton
/usr/bin/ld: test-skeleton.o: undefined reference to symbol 'g_file_read'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am on Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit platform. I searched for the error on the net and I came to conclusion that my glib 2.32 doesn't contain that functions. I successfully compiled and installed glib 2.38. But linker is looking for old glib 2.32 library. Here are libgio libraries in my computer:

```
 locate libgio-2.0.so.0
 /home/****/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
 /home/****/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.3200.3
 /home/****/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
 /home/****/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.3200.3
 /home/****/Downloads/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
 /home/****/Downloads/ubuntu-core-13.04-core-i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.3600.0
 /home/****/install/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
 /home/****/install/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.3800.2
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.3800.1
 /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
 /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.3600.0
 /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.3800.2
```

How can I tell the linker to use correct libgio that it is looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to link a specific library after looking at following weblinks:

- [How to add a path to LDFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254245/how-to-add-a-path-to-ldflags)
- [How to use ldflags while running configure](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-use-ldflags-while-running-configure-223322/)
- [How to link a specific version of a shared library in makefile without using LD_LIBRARY_PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384897/how-to-link-a-specific-version-of-a-shared-library-in-makefile-without-using-ld)
- [How to specify the library version to use at link time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840218/how-to-specify-the-library-version-to-use-at-link-time)
- [How do you link to a specific version of a shared library in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828053/how-do-you-link-to-a-specific-version-of-a-shared-library-in-gcc)

Specifically, setting `LDFLAGS` as,

```
LDFLAGS='-l:/usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.3800.2 -l:/usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3800.2 -l:/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.3800.2' ./configure
```

did the trick.