# How can I dynamically link stdlibc++.o.6 to my executable from a specified directory using cmake?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, makefile

I want to dynamically link stdlibc++ to my executable. I do not want to use the packages installed on my system. I want to be able to point a specific folder in my project directory that contains a specific version of stdlibc++ and dynamically link it from there. How can I do this using cmake? Once I attempt to link the lib the way I want to, how do I go about checking and making sure it actually linked to the specified library and not the default one?  Doing some research suggested I use a flag to turn off the default libs. However I would rather not do that. In my search, editing the rpath was another solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828053/how-do-you-link-to-a-specific-version-of-a-shared-library-in-gcc or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840218/how-to-specify-the-library-version-to-use-at-link-time or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384897/how-to-link-a-specific-version-of-a-shared-library-in-makefile-without-using-ld