# Linux C++ linker /usr/bin/ld

Tags: c++, linux, linker

I wrote a small application on Redhat Linux 6 using g++ 4.4.6. After compilation, I received an error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

I did a search for the crypto library and find them here,

```
[root@STL-DUNKEL01 bin]# find / -name libcrypto*
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.6
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

My question is whether the compilation error is caused by **/usr/bin/ld** not having **/usr/lib64/** in the search path? If yes, how can I add it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ld cannot find an existing library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/ld-cannot-find-an-existing-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the directories to search for the libraries in as a parameter to `gcc` like so `-L<directory_to_search_in>`. And note that there can be multiple parameters to `-L`. Also, are you trying to build a 32-bit application or a 64-bit one?

Answer (score 5):

No, you have likely incorrectly diagnosed the cause.

You need a `libcrypto.so` to link against.  This is usually a symlink to one of the actual libraries, whose soname (`libcrypto.so.??`) will be embedded into the binary.  Only that library is needed at runtime, but the symlink is necessary to compile.

See [Diego E. Pettenò: Linkers and names](http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2010/10/linkers-and-names) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `-L/usr/lib64` when calling gcc or ld.

Note, you can specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well/instead, but it is considered [harmful](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html) to do so.  (The link mentions Solaris specifically, but the issues apply to other OSs as well.)

Quote:

> - LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used in preference to any run time or default system linker path. If (God forbid) you had it set to something like /dcs/spod/baduser/lib, if there was a hacked version of libc in that directory (for example) your account could be compromised. It is for this reason that set-uid programs completely ignore LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
> - When code is compiled and depends on this to work, it can cause confusion where different versions of a library are installed in different directories, for example there is a libtiff in /usr/openwin/lib and /usr/local/lib. In this case, the former library is an older one used by some programs that come with Solaris.
> - Sometimes when using precompiled binaries they may have been built with 3rd party libraries in specific locations; ideally code should either ship with the libraries and install into a certain location or link the code as a pre-installation step. Solaris 7 introduces $ORIGIN which allows for a relative library location to be specified at run time (see the Solaris Linker and Libraries Guide). The alternative is to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on a per-program basis, either as a wrapper program to the real program or a shell alias. Note however, that LD_LIBRARY_PATH may be inherited by programs called by the wrapped one ...

Answer (score 2):

Add the directory to `/etc/ld.so.conf`

then run "sudo ldconfig" to make the changes take effect.