# OpenSSL ON WINDOWS!! - ld.exe cannot find -lcrypto/-leay32

Tags: c, windows, cryptography, openssl

I am trying to build a C file using OpenSSL on (64-bit) Windows 7.  I have downloaded the latest full binary from the official OpenSSL site, and am using MinGW, and have added the respective `bin` directories to `PATH`.  However I am getting the following error :

```
c:\Workspace\OSAccess\c>gcc -I%JAVA_HOME%\include -I%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -std=c99 -lm -lcrypto -o libosaccess.dll osaccess.c
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I cannot find any file called `libcrypto.dll` or `cryptolib.dll`, so I tried to build my own OpenSSL from source, using the install notes supplied, as I can see that the static libraries for `crypto` and `ssl` do not seem to be shipped with the Windows install.  I have seen references in other posts to a couple of other libraries, `libeay32` and `ssleay32`, but these return the same error.

If I remove the `-lcrypto` (or other) then I get `Undefined reference` errors:

```
c:\Workspace\OSAccess\c>gcc -I%java_home%\include -I%java_home%\include\win32 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -std=c99 -lm -o libosaccess.dll osaccess.c
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x383): undefined reference to 'Netbios@4'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to 'Netbios@4'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x445): undefined reference to 'Netbios@4'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x73d): undefined reference to 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x742): undefined reference to 'EVP_aes_256_cbc'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x76a): undefined reference to 'EVP_EncryptInit_ex'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x794): undefined reference to 'EVP_EncryptUpdate'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x7d2): undefined reference to 'EVP_EncryptFinal_ex'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x81c): undefined reference to 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x865): undefined reference to 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x86a): undefined reference to 'EVP_aes_256_cbc'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x892): undefined reference to 'EVP_DecryptInit_ex'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x8bc): undefined reference to 'EVP_DecryptUpdate'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x8fa): undefined reference to 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbi3e1T.o:osaccess.c:(.text+0x930): undefined reference to 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup'
```

Comment: Have a look on [cannot-find-libcrypto-library-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368671/cannot-find-libcrypto-library-error)

Comment: Adding `-Lc:\OpenSSL-Win64 -leay32` was the solution for this.

Comment: ... and `-Lc:\Windows\System32 -lnetapi32` for the Netbios error

Answer (score 0):

If  libcrypto.dll or cryptolib.dll are not there , i will recommend you to try and copy it from any other system . I had similar problem with , luckily found it on another system and copying worked well too.

Regards,
Jain