# Compile with linking against static and dynamic library for OpenSSL

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I want to compile my code including the OpenSSL library. For my purpose it is necessary to link the library ***statically***.

If I was dynamically linking the script for compilation would look like `g++ test.cpp -lcrypto -o test`.

I tried to use the `-static` option for the compilation, but if i do so i get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x15): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x2b): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x35): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_bind_func':
(.text+0x381): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_bind_func':
(.text+0x460): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_bind_var':
(.text+0x4e1): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_bind_var':
(.text+0x5c0): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_load':
(.text+0x630): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_load':
(.text+0x6a0): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_load':
(.text+0x6df): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
(.text+0x788): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dladdr'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
(.text+0x7d9): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In Funktion `dlfcn_unload':
(.text+0x834): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: @Sacx Actually these answers are pretty unsatisfying. If i follow the first answer, i do not get a statically linked binary (has the same size as the dynamically linked one). If i try to use the -static option instead of -static-libc, and I link -ldl additional to -lcrypto, i get the following warning: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): "In Funktion `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x15): Warnung: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking"

Comment: Why is it necessary to link the -ldl, which seems to be the dynamic linker library

Comment: I did the equivalent (static compile tcpdump) about 8 months ago.  It was a day-long slog of banging through different Google hits until I found the one that worked, and sorry no, I don't recall how I did it.  All that said, I'm voting to move this to Stack Overflow, as this is a Programming question and not a security Question.

Comment: the link of the first comment is the equivalent for Stack Overflow, @gowenfawr could you please put your solution there?

Comment: Again, I don't recall how I did it...  My advice to you is to bang your head against the wall repeatedly and try different things until something works.  Heck, that's how compiling packages worked when I was a kid (back before `configure`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find libcrypto library error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368671/cannot-find-libcrypto-library-error). `gcc` vs `g++` does not really matter in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> g++ test.cpp -lcrypto -o test
> ```

Try:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lcrypto -ldl
```

Order and placement of the library matter.

---

> For my purpose it is necessary to link the library statically.

My bad. I missed this earlier. For this, its easiest to perform:

```
g++ test.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a -o test -ldl
```

Some folks want to use `-Bstatic`, `L` and `-l`. But that's not portable (BSDs, OS X and iOS don't honor them).

An archive is just a collection of object files (`*.o`). So you can use the archive anywhere a object file is needed.

You can locate the libraries with:

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:    14.04
$ find /usr/lib -iname libcrypto.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
```

Also, `test` is a real program. Be sure to run it with `./test`. I usually name it `test.exe` to avoid collisions.

---

> what is the difference if i place the lib in front of the output file or after it?

The way to envision this is to convert this (with some hand waiving):

```
g++ test.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a -o test -ldl
```

Into:

```
g++ test.o libcrypto.o libssl.o -o test -ldl
```

The location of the output file (`-o test`) is not relevant. I use it to separate object (on the left) and libraries (on the right).

Comment: what is the difference if i place the lib in front of the output file or after it? @jww

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but have you tried replacing `-lcrypto -ldl` with `/path/to/libcrypto.a /path/to/libdl.a`?