# Solaris make error - ld: fatal: library -luutil: not found

Tags: unix, gcc, compiler-errors, solaris, zfs

Hi guys hoping some of you solaris wizards might be able to point me in the right direction...

Background:
I'm compiling a program that makes use of some of the zfs CLI code. (found here: https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/tree/master/usr/src/cmd/zfs)

Problem:
`libuutil.so.1` is present in `/usr/lib` but if I try to compile like so...

> $ gcc -lzfs -L/usr/lib -luutil -lnvpair
>
> ld: fatal: library -luutil: not found

Can anyone suggest a fix? Or a reason that the lib is not being found?

Thanks guys!

Comment: On my system, this file is actually a symlink into `/lib` -- but still doesn't work.

Comment: This seems similar to the following
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/ld-cannot-find-an-existing-library

Comment: kludge was to `cp /lib/libuutil.so.1 /lib/libuutil.so` I don't really understand the naming conventions... but at least now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link to a libuutil.so library. As explained in a post pointed to by Ben van Gompel and in this post:
https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/quick_fix_to_the_linker
You'd need to do:
`ln -s /usr/lib/libuutil.so.1 /usr/lib/libuutil.so`
This is because ld looks only for names that end in .so, not in number. This is a simple mechanism to have many versions of one library (version being designated by the number at the end) that can be used by compilation process.