# C++: linker cannot find -lcrypto, but the library is in the path

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, shared-libraries

I am compiling a C++ application using GNU `g++`. The project takes advantage of  OpenSSL libraries.

### Background

On my machine (a 64 bit CentOS quad core) I compile and link my files.

```
g++ -g -c -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib64/ 
    -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/local/ssl/include/ 
    -lcrypto mysrc1.cpp mysrc2.cpp mysrc3.cpp

g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib64/ -lcrypto 
    *.o -o ./myapp.out
```

My application uses function `MD5` which is contained in `libcrypto.so`. As you can see I specify to `g++` the dirs where to search using the `-L`, `-I` options and which libraries to look for with the `-l<lib-name>` option. There are some trivial paths like `/usr/local/lib` which can be omitted of course, but I specified them because the makefile is parametric.

### The problem

My problem is that I can successfully compile my stuff (first command), **but linking fails** (second command):

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [cppsims_par] Error 1

But I did check folders and everything... `libcrypto.so` is inside `/usr/lib64/`. What is going on?

Comment: Does the symlink point to an actual file?

Comment: ah... I get what you mean... gonna check

Comment: I have two files: `/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10` and `/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0`. When doing `ls -l` I can see the following path for the symlink: `/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0`. The last one is the extract from the `ls` command output.

Comment: Not answering your question, but note you want to link your object code and libs in most-to-least dependent order. (i.e. your .o's use libcrypto, so your link line should bring the .o's *first*, then -lcrypto). Some linkers, in particular ld for gcc, is rather finicky about this. But I likewise a curious why, if your paths are valid, `libcrypto` cannot be located.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Did as you said, but reversing places did not work... it is so damn frustrating... everything look fine, the lib is there and I do not know why it fails.

Comment: One thing you might try is adding `-v` to your gcc line. its rather noisy, but it should show *all* paths searched for path-required operations, including both include paths and linker paths. **Edit** also, get the -lcrypto out of your file-compile line. the line that compiles, but doesn't link, your `mysrc*.cpp` files. That isn't a link step, its a compile-only step and that should not be there. it should only be on your *last* line. Likewise, the lib-paths aren't required on that line either.

Comment: Is there anything in LD_LIBRARY_PATH that could be causing problems?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Ah yeah, thank you for the hint.. it's correct actually... I did remove library stuff from compiling line... however still getting the same problem... Gonna try the -v... but I did try the way the answer told me, the one below my question, please have a look at my comment there... -v should give me the same info of 'strace' regarding files somehow?

Answer (score 6):

It may help if you try strace to find why it failed the file lookup

```
strace -f -e trace=file g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib64/ -lcrypto 
    *.o -o ./myapp.out
```

Comment: Trying this... got an error and looked at the man page... maybe you meant: `-e trace=file`?

Comment: ah.. yes.  Corrected it

Comment: After running `strace` I can see that each line referencing `/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so` fails...

Comment: There are many many many lines like: `[pid 10780] open("/usr/lib/libcrypto.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)... but it reports paths for `libcrypto` which are not the same as the one I reported in the linking command. I told the compiler to look for `/usr/lib64/` but it is looking somewhere else...
`

Comment: btw there are so many errors... not only it cannot find this lib, the strace is showing other lines of not found files...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39366/discussion-between-tristan-and-andry)

Answer (score 3):

I did find the problem and it is related to this question: [ld cannot find an existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/ld-cannot-find-an-existing-library)

Actually I had no symlink `libcrypto.so` and the compiler was not able to find the library...

Answer (score 0):

I had related issue, and resolved it after inspecting the trace.

I had

`-L<my/path/to/lib> -llib_some_library`

when it should have been

`-L<my/path/to/lib> -lsome_library`