# ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I was trying to break down compilation to these four steps, but the last one seems problematic for me.

```
cpp hello.cpp > hello.i
g++ -S hello.i
as -o hello.o hello.s
ld -o hello hello.o -lstdc++
```

I searched the problem on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/335928/1904186) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16710047/1904186), but that didn't help.

Running in verbose mode gave me

```
attempt to open hello.o succeeded
hello.o
attempt to open /usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib32/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib32/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib32/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib32/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //lib32/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //lib32/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib32/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib32/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libstdc++.a failed
ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `g++ hello.cpp -Wl,--verbose` will get GCC to tell you where it's finding `libstdc++`.  That should give you a start to figuring out how to get `ld` to find it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of invoking the linker directly, try calling it indirectly through `gcc` or `g++`:

```
cpp hello.cpp > hello.i
g++ -S hello.i
as -o hello.o hello.s
g++ -o hello hello.o
```

Comment: I think that might not even be indirect… `ld` is now a different tool, deprecated for such purposes, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Actually my primary target was to study/learn/deal with linker ,and not to create an executable and `ld` command made me cry over that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had updated `gcc` to `gcc-10` but left `g++` at an older version (`g++-9`).

The fix was to install `g++-10`.