# using sndfile library when compiling 32bit linux application on Fedora 20 x86_64

Tags: c++, linux, linker, ld, libsndfile

I'm currently using Fedora 20 x86_64.
I've built libsndfile with these commands:

```
sudo ./configure BASE_FLAGS=-32
sudo make
sudo make install
```

This all goes well and I can find the compiled library in /usr/local/lib.
I want to use this in an application that will be built in 32bit.
The problem occurs when I try to compile that application. I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /builddir/Code/Platformer/../Dependencies/libsndfile/lib/Linux/libsndfile.so when searching for -lsndfile  
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /builddir/Code/Platformer/../Dependencies/libsndfile/lib/Linux/libsndfile.a when searching for -lsndfile
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsndfile
```

The "skipping incompatible" might suggest that I'm doing something wrong when compiling sndfile but since I'm kind of new to this I can't find what it is. I tried different configurations but they all have the same result.

If this needs more code or something, let me know what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem - try to look here:

[ld cannot find an existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/ld-cannot-find-an-existing-library)

Generally there is probably a symlink missing, because the '-devel' library is not istalled. That is why

```
sudo yum install libsndfile-devel.*
```

fixed it for me.