# How to eliminate ld errors in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I'm getting following errors after running `make` command:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLESv2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lepoxy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lEGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLESv2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lepoxy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lEGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLESv2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lepoxy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lEGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -laio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssh2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncursesw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
main/CMakeFiles/esesc.dir/build.make:163: recipe for target 'main/esesc' failed
make[2]: *** [main/esesc] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1041: recipe for target 'main/CMakeFiles/esesc.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [main/CMakeFiles/esesc.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried to search online in these links:
[ld cannot find an existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/ld-cannot-find-an-existing-library)

[usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

Here I see that every library has to be linked symbolically with the existing library but I'm unsure of doing that. Can anyone please suggest me any technique for doing this?

I know `locate <library>` and `ln` commands. Now how to eliminate the above errors using this? Can anyone please elaborate on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it means you didn't install needed dependencies.
did you install at least libs from this manual? https://github.com/masc-ucsc/esesc/blob/master/docs/Usage.md

```
 sudo apt-get install libepoxy0 libepoxy-dev
```

should remove epoxy warning, for example

Answer (score 0):

Your link command probably needs a -L to precede those -l.

Search your system for those libnames, for example  GLESv2.

I use "locate GLESv2".   (Note: locate uses what "sudo updatedb" updates)

On my Unbuntu, the following  lines are reported by locate.

```
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so.2
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
```

For the so (the shared object library) found in the first dir, you might try adding the following to your build command.

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

And repeat for any library name not yet resolved.

Here is an example from my Makefile - note the relative path to a collection of libraries I wrote in a directory "bag"

---

```
R01: dtb_acs.cc 
rm -f dtb_acs 
g++ -m64 -O3 -ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall-Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor
 -pedantic -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wunused
 -Woverloaded-virtual   
  -O0   dtb_acs.cc  -o dtb_acs  
 -L../../bag -lbag_i686 -lposix_i686 -lrt -pthread
 ^^^^^^^^^^^ three -l<libname> are in the -L dir
```

---

If needed (because the effort did not resolve anything), try adding -l and a specific library, such as -llibGLESv2.so  (or .a, as the case may be)

Good luck.

Comment: There are a _lot_ of .so libraries in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.