# How can I build a similar docker image based on alpine that works on ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, alpine-linux

I am trying to rewrite a Dockerfile (https://github.com/orangefoil/rcssserver-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) so that it uses alpine instead of ubuntu. Goal is to reduce the file size.

In the original image the robocup soccer server is built from scratch using g++, flex, bison, etc.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS build
ARG VERSION=16.0.0
WORKDIR /root
RUN apt update && \
    apt -y install autoconf bison clang flex libboost-dev libboost-all-dev libc6-dev make wget
RUN wget https://github.com/rcsoccersim/rcssserver/archive/rcssserver-$VERSION.tar.gz && \
    tar xfz rcssserver-$VERSION.tar.gz && \
    cd rcssserver-rcssserver-$VERSION && \
    ./bootstrap && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig
```

I tried to do the same on alpine and had to exchange some packages:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ARG VERSION=16.0.0
WORKDIR /root
# Add basics first
RUN apk — no-cache update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add autoconf bison clang-dev flex-dev boost-dev make wget automake libtool-dev g++ build-base
RUN wget https://github.com/rcsoccersim/rcssserver/archive/rcssserver-$VERSION.tar.gz
RUN tar xfz rcssserver-$VERSION.tar.gz
RUN cd rcssserver-rcssserver-$VERSION && \
    ./bootstrap && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig
```

Unfortunately, my version doesn't work yet. It fails with

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lrcssclangparser
```

From what I found so far, this can happen, if dev packages are not installed (see [ld cannot find an existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335928/ld-cannot-find-an-existing-library)), but I changed to dev packages where I could find them and still no luck.

So, my current assumption is that ubuntu has some package installed, that I need to add in my alpine image. I would exclude a code problem, since the ubuntu version works.

Any ideas, what could be missing? I would also be happy to understand how to compare the packages myself, but the package namings are not the same in ubuntu and alpine, so I find it pretty hard to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break this up using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  In the image you're building now, the final image contains the C toolchain and all of the development libraries and headers that those `-dev` packages install; you don't need any of those to actually run the built application.  The basic idea is to build the application exactly as you have it now, but then `COPY` only the built application into a new image with fewer dependencies.

This would look something like this (untested):

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS build
# ... exactly what's in the original question ...

FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install the shared libraries you need to run the application,
# but not -dev headers or the full C toolchain.  You may need to
# run `ldd` on the built binary to see what exactly it needs.
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      libboost-atomic1.65.1 \
      libboost-chrono1.65.1 \
      # ... more libboost-* libraries as required ...

# Get the built application out of the original image.
# Autoconf's default is to install into /usr/local, and in a
# typical Docker base image nothing else will be installed there.
COPY --from=build /usr/local /usr/local
RUN ldconfig

# Describe how to run a container.
EXPOSE 12345
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/rcssserver"]
```

Compared to the size of the C toolchain, header files, and build-time libraries, the difference between an Alpine and Ubuntu image is pretty small, and Alpine has well-documented library compatibility issues with its minimal libc implementation.

Comment: So you would suggest to drop the alpine idea and directly go with ubuntu? In that case, I can stick directly with https://github.com/orangefoil/rcssserver-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile, since this is a multi-stage build already.

Comment: I accepted the answer for 2 reasons:
* The compatibility reasons that are probably at work here
* The fact that ubuntu for docker is actually ubuntu-minimal right now, which is not massively so different from alpine (still slightly bigger but not relevant).