# Why can't `ld` find `glfw3` even though my system has `/usr/lib/libglfw.so.3` file?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ld, glfw

I was trying to build a file using:

```sh
$ g++ tutorial.cpp   -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lm   -o tutorial
```

And was getting:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the package and the file were already there:

```sh
$ pacman -Ql glfw-x11
```

```
glfw-x11 /usr/
glfw-x11 /usr/include/
glfw-x11 /usr/include/GLFW/
glfw-x11 /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
glfw-x11 /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/cmake/
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/cmake/glfw3/
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.cmake
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets-noconfig.cmake
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets.cmake
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/libglfw.so
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3.3
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/pkgconfig/
glfw-x11 /usr/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
glfw-x11 /usr/share/
glfw-x11 /usr/share/licenses/
glfw-x11 /usr/share/licenses/glfw-x11/
glfw-x11 /usr/share/licenses/glfw-x11/LICENSE.md
```

I saw instructions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/335928/11541841) (about other library) to make a link of the files:

> The problem is the linker is looking for `libmagic.so` but you only
> have `libmagic.so.1`
>
> A quick hack is to symlink `libmagic.so.1` to `libmagic.so`

I looked up and my system did have it:

```sh
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libglfw*
```

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 abr 13 12:04 /usr/lib/libglfw.so -> libglfw.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 abr 13 12:04 /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3 -> libglfw.so.3.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 285504 abr 13 12:04 /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3.3
```

As a saw on another answer:

> As just formulated by grepsedawk, the answer lies in the `-l` option of `g++`, calling `ld`. If you
> look at the man page of this command, you can either do:
>
> - `g++ -l:libmagic.so.1 [...]`

I tried, and this did work:

```sh
$ g++ tutorial.cpp   -lGL -lGLEW -l:libglfw.so.3 -lm   -o tutorial
```

Later on, I saw this also worked:

```sh
$ g++ tutorial.cpp   -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw -lm   -o tutorial
```

Why does this happens?

Comment: Some `64 bit` systems have `/use/lib` and `/usr/lib64` and you may need to install the `64 bit` version of the library.

Comment: *"the file were already there"* -- Sorry, I do not see where in that list a file named `libglfw3.so` or `libglfw3.a` is. Where do you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because it’s `libglfw.so` and the linker searches for `libglfw3.so` because you specified `-lglfw3`. Use `-lglfw` instead.